# Adding documentation after modifying the code

Tags: documentation, team-foundation-server

In our TFS (Version 14.102.25423.0) I can click Browse on home page, then under Browse Server, pick my project and hit Navigate. Once inside my project, I see tabs like

> ```
> Home    Code    Work    Build    Test    RELEASE
> ```

Question: Sometimes I need to update code with no prior plan - no user stories, test, release plan etc. Once the app is updated, I need to go to TFS and document the changes I've made (apart from the documentation within the .cs files ofcourse). Something of the sort "Today I found a bug in such and such feature which was causing such and such damage, and I did such and such changes to remove it"

Where exactly do I enter this information?

Comment: Create a new bug in TFS before you check in and tie your changeset back to that bug.

Comment: This worked out great! Also, it seems you can't tie to that bug once it's been checked in. At least I could not find an option in History > Changeset Details

Comment: There is a way @greatbear302 but I can't remember how and I don't work with TFS anymore. Dig around some more. Add a link from the bug to the changeset maybe? I do remember needing to do it from the bug.